# How to use 'data-id' using selenium webdriver using python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to click an element identified by data-id but there is no direct support for accessing data-id elements in selenium webdriver using python. I am using geckodriver.

here is the html i am handling :

```
<div data-id="5+0">
    <div class="clock">5+0</div>
    <div class="perf">Blitz</div>
</div>
```

I need to click on any of these div elements. Also there is a ''flex'' mark beside the outer div, i don't know if that is significant in this case.

```
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('clock'):
    print(elem)
```

gives me a list of web elements but how to work with them? It has only session id and element id.

I am absolute newbie in selenium. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following `css selector` to click on the element.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-id='5+0']>div.clock").click()
```